# move DNS server to new hardware

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, windows-server-2012-r2

so we are running her at work ,a small network and we just get a new machine and since its a better machine we decided to use it for DNS .
so my question is what is the best way ,to take all the config from the old machine and give it to the new one , that won't create problems in the future .

P.S we are using windows server 2012 R2

Comment: If you are running it in a domain, join it to the domain as a domain controller (This will give you redundancy for AD too) providing replication works correctly, all the dns zones will be propagated over, providing they have been configured to do so in the first place

Answer (score 1):

It depends.

Is this a DNS server for AD? If so, is the AD DNS zone AD integrated? If so, set up your new server as a DC and DNS server. The DNS zones will be replicated to the new server automatically.

Is this a standalone DNS server not related to AD? If so then set up a secondary DNS zone on this new server for the DNS zone on your existing server. When you shut down the existing DNS server you can change the zone to a primary zone on the new server.